# ".media" domain is not recognized by mobile browser and instead the address is used as a search term

Tags: android, mobile-browser, tld, address-bar

My company has a web address that is in the `.media` domain.
We wanted to use this web address as a landing page for an Android application.

The problem we have is that when people use the Android internet browser and enter the domain, it instead does a Google search using the domain as the search term. Obviously I'd expected it to deliver the page direct.

Is this a bug with the Android internet browser? Should I expect it to operate this way and submit a bug report or are my assumptions inccorect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely a problem with the browser's name lookup. `media.` is a perfectly legitimate top-level domain, and Android should treat it as such.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Calle. I will submit a bug report I think.